# what does ''hefty scoop'' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

It's a psychology text and I have a problem understanding the bold part:

> But still, the advice to be more mindful often contains **a hefty
>   scoop of moralizing smugness**, a kind of “moment-shaming” for the
>   distractible, like a stern teacher scolding us for failing to
>   concentrate in class.

what does ''hefty scoop of moralizing smugness'' mean?

what's the general idea of this paragraph ?

Answer (score 1):

[Hefty](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/hefty):  "very large"

[Scoop](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/scoop):  "the amount of something that is held in a scoop"

Here the idiom "hefty scoop" is used figuratively to mean "a large amount".  The author is saying that those spiritual teachers who encourage "mindfulness" often have a kind of "I'm better than you because I can meditate" attitude.

You can of course use it literally:

> Mom added a hefty scoop of vanilla ice cream to the bowl before adding chocolate syrup and candy sprinkles.

[Edit]  See also [sanctimonous](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/sanctimonious) "pretending to be morally better than other people"

Comment: I wouldn't assume that figurative uses are easily understood once the literal meaning is figured out – understanding figurative uses can be _very_ tricky for the non-native speaker.

Comment: @J.R. fair enough, edited my answer.

Comment: @Andrew  it means a large amount of smugness.right?  what role does this '' moralizing'' play here?

Comment: @MasihK [Moralize](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/moralize) ("to express beliefs about what is good behavior and what is bad behavior").  Put together, "moralizing smugness" implies the person is doing this in a [sanctimonious](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/sanctimonious) manner, ("pretending to be morally better than other people")

Comment: @Andrew You made it really clear. but isn't smugness the object of moralize(transitive). to me according to dictionaries it means whether: to express good and bad aspects(behavior) of being smug or: to imrove the morality of being smug. I'm not sure but I think if smug were used as an adjective it would've made more sense. right?

Comment: @MasihK  I agree it's an odd construction, but not unusual.  In this case *smugness* is the noun, and *moralizing* is the modifying adjective.  It has the same meaning as if the author said "to moralize smugly".  Here the author is "forcing" the noun to make the metaphor work with "a hefty scoop" -- you have to scoop *something*, even figuratively.  Although I wonder if this doesn't deserve a question of its own.

Comment: @Andrew Yes.you're right. Thank you. you've been very patient.

Answer (score 0):

**Hefty** generally refers to something bulky and heavy. In this case, a 'hefty scoop' refers to a large amount, with some implication that it weighs down or overwhelms other elements of the conversation.

The general idea will vary somewhat depending on context, but roughly "Advice to be more mindful will often be received as hypocritical and judgemental".

Comment: I'm talking more about ''moralizing smugness'' here and the relationship between first part of this paragraph and the example that the writer gave.